# Need to Modify My docker-compose file for persist data and volume

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, persistent-volumes

Hi I have written a docker-compose file and It is working but I am not able to located it volume location.
I wanted to write **proper docker-compose file for a persistent volume and have a MongoDB on there**. **I feel that the Docker file I wrote is incorrect**.

Just to note The current docker-file is working and show persistent data.

I need to improve the file and also as a next step want to **add a PostgreSQL server same persistent in this via this compose file**.

Also how to find which containerID is is related to which volume ID/Name ?

Please **give me some suggestion and regarding my mistakes**.

**My code**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
mongodb:
 image: mongo
 restart: always
 container_name: database
 ports:
  - 27017:27017
 environment:
   MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: name
   MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
   MONGODB_URL: mongodb://database:27017
   volume: /home/zinja/Documents/driveA/mongodbdata/:/data/database
```

---

Also the information regrading the

**volume:/path1:/path2**

syntax is little confusing to me any comment on this are welcome.

---

Comment: You have `volume:` underneath `environment:` and so it sets an environment variable instead of defining a mount point.  It needs to be up one level in the YAML, and spelled [`volumes:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#short-syntax-3) (plural), and the mount definition needs to be in a list underneath it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Also I have found several volumes on my machine with VOLUME NAME by $docker volume ls with a long string. How do I map them to the containerIDs

Comment: You don't map them. You edit the compose file to use the appropriate tags rather than under the environment section